# Как использовать private переменную абстрактного класса?

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Client {

    public Client(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    private double balance;

    public double getBalance() {return balance;}    

    public void takeMoney(double withdraw){
        balance -= withdraw;
    }
    public void giveMoney(double amount){
        balance += amount;}

    public void printCount(){
        System.out.println(balance);
    }        
}
```

Первый наследник работает.

```
public class ClientPerson extends Client {

    public ClientPerson(double balance) {
        super(balance);
    }
}
```

Но, если переопределять метод, переменную balance в методе не видит. Как cделать этот метод рабочим?

```
public class ClientCompany extends Client {
    public ClientCompany(double balance) {
        super(balance);
    }

    @Override
    public void takeMoney(double withdraw) {
         balance -= (withdraw * 1.01);
    }
}
```

Comment: использовать тип protected вместо private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас же есть интерфейсная часть базового класса, который в свою очередь инкапсулирует свое состояние и имеет некоторое поведение (через свои методы).

Вот и используйте их, иначе зачем они нужны?:

```
public class ClientCompany extends Client {
    public ClientCompany(double balance) {
        super(balance);
    }

    @Override
    public void takeMoney(double withdraw) {
        super.takeMoney(withdraw * 1.01);        
    }
}
```

А лучше так (без магии):

```
public class ClientCompany extends Client {
    private double interestRate = 1.01;

    void setInterestRate(double value) {
        this.interestRate = value;
    }

    double getInterestRate() {
        return this.interestRate;
    } 

    @Override
    public void takeMoney(double withdraw) {
        super.takeMoney(withdraw * this.interestRate);        
    }
}
```